# Troubleshoot a simple Python code to input data and scrape output result from a website

Tags: python, web

I am no programmer, just generated this code using ChatGPT and some basic logic my little brain understands.

I want to input a PSSH value into a website, it has only one input field in it.
When pressed the Send button, it generates an output, which I want to scrape and display in my console.

Website: https://cdrm-project.com/findpssh
PSSH: AAAAQXBzc2gAAAAA7e+LqXnWSs6jyCfc1R0h7QAAACEIARIQriPE7lcBTSieCCGtu9/r+SIJNDAwMDAwOTc1OAA=

When done manually on the website, the output box displays the desired result which is "Cached PSSH..."
When executed the below python code, the python code does successfully scrape the output, but the output is "Not Found" which happens when we input a wrong value on that website field.

Here's the code:

```
import requests

# Set the URL of the website

url = "https://cdrm-project.com/findpssh"

# Set the PSSH value to input

pssh_value = "AAAAQXBzc2gAAAAA7e+LqXnWSs6jyCfc1R0h7QAAACEIARIQriPE7lcBTSieCCGtu9/r+SIJNDAwMDAwOTc1OAA="

# Set the data to send in the POST request

payload = {'pssh': pssh_value}

# Send the POST request to the website and get the response

response = requests.post(url, data=payload)

# Extract the result from the response content

result = response.content.decode()

# Print the result in the console

print(result)\
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to replace `payload = {'pssh': pssh_value}` with `payload = pssh_value`. If you look at the javascript on the website [ right click > View page source > Sources > cdrm-project.com > static > search.js, on google chrome ] then you can see the way it's done on the website:

```
async function server_request() {
  async function server_request_data() {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML =
      'Searching the database';

    const response = await fetch('/findpssh', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      },
      body: document.getElementById('pssh').value,
    });
    return await response.text();
  }
```

As you can see, the `body` of the request only contains the `pssh` value, not a dictionary like the code shared.

[image: Find PSSH Javascript Snippet]